# updating a record I just created

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a personnel recruitment website and am having an issue with adding new data to a record created on the previous page.

For ease of use, I have split the form into a number of steps (each step being on a new page), where Step 1 creates the record in the candidate database table and inserts the candidate's personal details (name, surname, contact details, gender, etc.) and sends the user to the next page (Step 2), where an profile pic can be uploaded and the path to the image is inserted into a field in the newly created record.

The problem comes in that I can't seem to get the code to call the record ID of the relevant record.  I thought of using mysql_insert_id but the issue with that is twofold.  Firstly, I'm not sure if I know how to use this correctly and multiple Google searches on this have left me none the wiser.  Secondly, as the company will have multiple branches around the country, there is a likelihood that two users could be adding candidates at the same time and User A could end up adding the photo to the record that User B created.

I have tried using $_POST to get the record ID but the data doesn't seem to be passing the data to the next page once it has been inserted into the table.

I am not exactly new to PHP but this is not something I have done before because I used to have a friend who would handle this kind of thing but he, unfortunately, passed away a few months ago so I am having to learn how to do this as I go along, with little success.

I hope I am being clear enough about my problem because I am at a bit of a loss.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! Be sure to upvote ALL answers that you find useful, including those to others' questions. And check/accept the best answer to your own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would use PDO (or mysqli) insetead of the deprecated mysql_* extensions.

Using PDO, after you execute your statement, you can use two functions to get the ID you need:

```
$stmt->execute($values);     // $stmt contains the prepared statement

$return_code = $stmt->rowCount();
// $return_code = 1 : new record
// $return_code = 2 : updated record

if ($return_code == 1)
{
    $ID_YOU_NEED = $db->lastInsertId();    // $db is the database connection
}
```

By the way, I use `rowCount()` because I normally use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` on most of my insert queries, you could possibly skip that step.

Then I would store the ID in a session <strike>or add it as a hidden field for the next form</strike>.

By the way, depending on the requirements, I would not store anything in a db just yet until all required information has come in.

Comment: -1 Never store the dbms id as a hidden field since there is no security--anyone could change the value and thereby have access to other people's records in the database.

Comment: @Larry K I guess you're right, in this case that would be a bad idea; I'm working a lot on a system right now where only the admin can edit data and didn't read the question thoroughly (although I would probably have a hidden variable to match another session variable anyway)...

Comment: Again, thans for the feedback. Your last bit of advice ("I would not store anything in a db just yet until all required information has come in") got me thinking. I think I have realised a work-around to my problem. I am actually running out of time on this phase of the project and getting this lastInsertId thingy is proving time-consuming (I think sleep deprivation is taking its toll).   I know sessions and, by using sessions, I don't have to call the last ID because I gather all the data and then insert the record right at the end of the whole process.  Would you say my logic is sound here?

Comment: @UbuntuElphie That's probably what I would do as well.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off using php PDO . In that, there is a function that gets the ID of the row inserted ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php ). When you run your insert code, run that right after it and it will give you the ID of the row that you just inserted. Now, attach that ID to links for the user or a session variable (or anything else that is user-specific) and you will be able to easily track the last row that each person will be able to edit.

Comment: It would be better to store in a session and keep it completely invisible and server side. Passing it in links or as form information presents security issues.

Comment: Yup, I totally agree with you, but it seems that this chap is quite new to programming or at least PHP and getting it to work would probably be easier via a link at first. When he has it working and understands the concepts, then I would say he can go back and harden the code against security problems. Again though, not disagreeing with your comment though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. @Fluffeh, you are dead right that I am new to this.  My PHP skills up to now have only required me to do the bare minimum so that my mate could come in and do what was needed to be done to make the code work like it is meant to.  As mentioned, he died halfway into this project so I am fumbling around in the dark a little here while I find my feet.

Answer (score 0):

First,

in your page which inserts the record into the database, you need to get the id of the newly created record. Use [mysqli::insert-id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) There are also other ways to do it.

Second,

Store the record id in the user's session and use it in subsequent pages for updating the record. It is important for security reasons to store the id in the session, not as a url GET value nor as a "hidden" field.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I will definitely use sessions rather than a hidden field (I have been previously advised against a url GET Value but, up to no, having read the feedback I have received, hadn't realised the vulnerability of a hidden field)